# Delete tr using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, delete-row

I have created a table and want to remove the rows with jquery.

I have looked everywhere and I cannot work out what I have done wrong.

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ao-referrer-summary").on('click', '.btnDelete', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<table id="ao-referrer-summary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Referrer First Name</th>
            <th>Referrer Last Name</th>
            <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>%%FNAME%%</td>
            <td>%%LNAME%%</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btnDelete">&times;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%%FNAME%%</td>
            <td>%%LNAME%%</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btnDelete">&times;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/designstreet1/4pvrtghu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working just need to load  `jQuery library` to make it work. Choose the jquery library at upper left dropdown list. Thats how to use [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/). And after that you're good to go mate. See screenshot below :

[image]

And if you're using code snippet, here the section to include library :

[image]

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/9qdcxamu/)**

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry being such an idiot. Im very new to the whole js fiddle thing

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ao-referrer-summary").on('click', '.btnDelete', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ao-referrer-summary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Referrer First Name</th>
            <th>Referrer Last Name</th>
            <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>%%FNAME%%</td>
            <td>%%LNAME%%</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btnDelete">&times;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%%FNAME%%</td>
            <td>%%LNAME%%</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btnDelete">&times;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Problem is Missing Script. Code is ok

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include jquery library in order to make your js code work.

[image: Screen shot here, and above is the updated fiddle link]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ao-referrer-summary").on('click', '.btnDelete', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="ao-referrer-summary">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Referrer First Name</th>
            <th>Referrer Last Name</th>
            <th>Delete User</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>%%FNAME%%</td>
            <td>%%LNAME%%</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btnDelete">&times;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>%%FNAME%%</td>
            <td>%%LNAME%%</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btnDelete">&times;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4pvrtghu/2/